# Assign model method's return value to model attribute

Tags: python, django

I have a class similar to this:

```
class X(models.Model):
  def hello(self):
    return "Humpty Dumpty"

  name = (hello,)
  age = models.IntegerField()
```

now when I run in the console: `y.name` being `y` an instance, I get the following:

> (property object at 0x0000000004FDCBD8,)

What am I doing wrong here?

I tried using the `@property` above the method but it didn't work.

I'd like to get "Humpty Dumpty" when I access `y.name`. So the method would assign it's value to the attribute.

Comment: You haven't said what you want that assignment to do. Also, I can't reproduce the "property object" value you see printed.

Comment: @NedBatchelder my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the function called on attribute access, define name as property and provide your function `foo` to it:

```
name = property(hello)
```

This will set the `fget` inside the property to your function `hello`.

```
y = X()
y.name
'Humpty Dumpty'
```

Take note, there's a pretty good [tutorial on descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) in the Python Official docs.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I couldn't find precise documentation on this.

Comment: Could you also tell how to use a method inside another?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by that, call a method inside another method?

Comment: Just call it, you get `self` passed in every method implicitly so just use `self.method_name()` to call it.

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid syntax. You need to do something like this:

```
class X:
  def __init__(self):
      self.name = self.hello()

  def hello(self):
    return "Humpty Dumpty"

test = X()
print(test.name) # prints "Humpty Dumpty"
```

Comment: Is this in django? I added the python tag because I think it might be something more specific to python